# Custom JS code is not working for Wordpress WPForms

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode, wpforms

I have created a custom js code that adds validation to postal code.
I accessed the relevant fields and added conditions.

```
 var postalCodeInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.wpf-postal-code-char-requirement');
    for (var i = 0; i < postalCodeInputs.length; i++) {
        postalCodeInputs[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
            var maxLength = 5;
            var input = this;
            if (input.value.length > maxLength) {
                input.value = input.value.slice(0, maxLength);
            }
            if (input.value.length < maxLength) {
                // Create an error message element
                var errorMessage = document.createElement('div');
                errorMessage.className = 'ihc-register-notice error-postcode';
                errorMessage.textContent = 'Postal code must be 5 characters long.';
                
                // Find the target div with id 'ihc_reg_number_7248' and append the error message to it
                var targetDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('ihc-form-create-edit')[0].children[7]

            var errorexist = document.getElementsByClassName('error-postcode');
                if(errorexist.length==0){
                targetDiv.appendChild(errorMessage);
}

            } else {
                // If the input is valid, remove any existing error message
                var existingErrorMessage = document.getElementsByClassName('error-postcode');
                if (existingErrorMessage.length>0) {
                    existingErrorMessage[0].remove();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I also tried adding event listener of DOMContentLoaded

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // The same code as above
});
```

The issue is, when I run the above code in browser directly (by adding in console editor), it works fine. But when I add custom JS code to WPForms , it doesnot work.

[image: Adding Custom JS Code WPForms]

Comment: I can see it's included in `<head>` so that may indeed be the problem. First try putting it in `<footer>`. If that doesn't solve it just temporarily try setting it to run after a timeout of 1 second and see if it works then. The most obvious problem looks like DOMContentLoaded is still triggered before `.wpf-postal-code-char-requirement` exists, and if so you need to figure out the best way to wait until it does.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I tried this.
But I think the issue is not with the code, it is something with the extension, as javascript is not being applied on the website. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: This was solved. Due to uniform text formatting of the code editor, I couldn't notice that this was a comment block and I added the code in that, so it wasn't getting applied.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because op answered it themselves with a comment